# Deploying SSIS 2010 to Integration Service Catalog SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am new in using the SSIS and had created my first project on SSIS2010 Shell. At the moment, I have reached the stage to deploy the project to the SSISDB which has been created through the Integration Service Catalog. However, I battled for hours and hours to get the project deployed but has zero luck as it always fails and gives me an error of:

> Failed to deploy project. For more information, query the
>   operation_messages view for the operation identifier '18'.

I ran the following query on the SSISDB level to diagnose or look at the the position of the error but didn't clarify anything to me and it sounds even more ambiguous:

> SELECT [message]   FROM [SSISDB].[internal].[operation_messages]
>   where [operation_id] = 18

I also created two Nonclustered Indexes on the SSISDB to run the process faster in case of time out issue, but this didn't work either!

Within the Additional Data in the error log I have notice the following message:

> Server Name: DODI Error Number: 27203 Severity: 16 State: 1 Procedure:
>   deploy_project Line Number: 139

I have no idea why the project fail to be deployed? I spent hours looking at similar error, most of I already tried, as it seems fairly complicated! Does any one know the solution for this problem??

Comment: At a guess your development tool is too old for the SQL Server version. Can you press help/about and find out what your dev tool is called (SSIS 2010 Shell is not anything I've heard of maybe you mean VS 2010 Shell?) What version is your SQL Server (you should see it in the object browser in SSMS when you connect to the SQL Server)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01586 SP1Re and the SSMS is SQL Server 2012!

Comment: It's very confusing but I _think_ that VS2010 and SQL 2012 are totally compatible. So I'm not sure what your issue is.

Comment: Just to add SSMS that I am using, is Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 1.0.5388.0. Trust me Nick, I spent the whole day just trying to figure out the problem but has no luck so far! The error is completely unclear.

Comment: Unfortunately the client tools for SSIS are a complete and utter mess of incompatibilities and confusing and ambiguous naming. You could try downloading and installing "SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015"  as per here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522577.aspx

Comment: Can I convert my project from VS 2010 to 2015 though ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133498/discussion-between-dodi82-and-nick-mcdermaid).

Comment: Hi Nick,I managed to fix issues in the project and can open the project in VS 2015 but the problem is still reading 2010?